# How to crop not stretch an image in a slider? I've tried 'background:cover'

Tags: html, css, image, slider, stretch

I've began editing a pre-made Blogger/Blogspot template (as an amateur!!), and have come across photos in posts on a featured slider that stretch to fit the slider and look terrible. Here is the original template website where I downloaded the file: [Sora Templates - 'Blogging'](http://www.soratemplates.com/2015/06/blogging-blogger-templates.html), and it looks amazing on the example. Except my photos are not set sizes, and it would take me a very long time to crop them all to the same size.

Here is where I believe the right code is located (without images as the images are found in my posts), but I cannot seem to get `Background-size: cover;` to work, nor 'clip'. Is there a way to automatically have them cropped?

```css
.related-posts{
margin:0 0% 0 0%;
background:#fff;
}
#related-posts{
border-top:1px solid #CCC;
position:relative;
padding-top:.51em;
}
.related-posts img{
border:1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
h2.relatedpost{
position:absolute;
top:-15px;
padding:0 5px 0 0;
text-indent:15px;
background:#FFF;
margin-bottom:0
}
.related-content{
float:left;

}
.related-content{}
.relatedtitle{
color:#414141;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:17px!important;
}
.slider{
height: 382px!important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #6d6e71;
}

.large-category-header {
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

ul.bjqs{
position:relative;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0 0px 0;
overflow:hidden;
height:385.333333px!important;
width:100%!important;
display:block!important;
}
li.bjqs-slide{
position:absolute;
display:none;
list-style:none;
height:99%!important;
width:99.5%!important;
}
ul.bjqs-controls{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index:9999;
}
li.slider-content img{
width:100%;
}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a,ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{
display:none;
}
ol.bjqs-markers{
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{
  margin-top: -34px;
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 7px 4px 7px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 98%;
  background: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0px !important;
}
ol.bjqs-markers li{
display:inline;
}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{
display:inline-block;
}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{
display:none;
}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
.featured-title{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 93.5%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}
.featured-posts-section{
background:#f9f9f9;
border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
padding-top:20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.featured-title a{
color:#fff;
}
.status-msg-wrap{display:none;}
.fpimg{
width:100% !important;
height:380px;
}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{
background: #fff;
color: #fff;
margin: 5px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 240px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 10px;
}
ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a,
ol.bjqs-markers li a:hover{
background:#F26F6F;
}
p.bjqs-caption{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class='slider' id='slider'>
<div class='large-category-header'><img alt='Featured' src='http://i1329.photobucket.com/albums/w557/iSharnie/sites%20stuff%202/featured_zpsvedkkd5i.png'/></div>
<ul class='bjqs'>
<script type='text/javaScript'>
//<![CDATA[
document.write("<script src=\"/feeds/posts/default?max-results="+numposts1+"&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showhomeposts1\"><\/script>");
//]]></script>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: Yes! It's so frustrating because I don't know firstly if it's not working because I can't find where I need to put it, or just because `background-size: cover;` doesn't work. Would you know where it should be put?

Comment: I've looked at the live example, and `background` css rules won't work, because the javascript inserts actual images into your slider. Dealing with images make it tricky to achieve what you need to do without cropping/resizing your images.

Comment: That template is using a fixed height (275px) for its images being inserted into the slider as <li> items. Its not using background-image as their source. So, you will either have to replace that slider with a different plugin or do some manipulation to it to get it the exact way you want. the css in that theme also uses !important attributes, so unless those are removed, it may be even more difficult to achieve. See here: http://pasteboard.co/1z0LOJTK.png

Comment: @MichaelG That makes sense, only I cannot find that line of script with fixed height 275px on my own template, weirdly. It's probably me, I'm not particularly experienced at this. Thank you for that answer though! I'm glad I know why I couldn't get the background-size to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the script is actually controlling the height of the slider and its images, as in your CSS being placed into your index (dynamically) somehow, shows the "fpimg" class overriding the height and width of images placed. http://pasteboard.co/1z2hCJkX.png

Technically, if you could get into that code, if its a plugin or script, and instead of using an `<img>` source, and in the `<a>` add a background image setting in that class which loads the image you want, into the  itself, you can then use background-size cover.

BUT, without having first hand access to that file or theme myself, that's about as much i can do at the moment. =) I recommend reaching out for assistance and seeing if someone can alter that plugin/script to use a background img instead of placing an actual image in the slider.